# fs.readdir Not Reading The Path Passed As The Argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm trying to read all files in a directory using fs. When i call the fs.readdir function I get the error

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\dev\main\file:\C:\dev\main\public'

When I console log the value I pass to the function it prints

> file:///C:/dev/main/public

This is the code.

```
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');

export let readDir = './';
let files = [];

if (readDir !== './') {
    console.log(url.pathToFileURL(readDir).href);
    fs.readdir(url.pathToFileURL(readDir).href, (err, dir) => {
        if (err){
            throw err;

        }
    })
}
```

**Why is the readdir function not reading from the directory I passed to it?**

Comment: Can you please edit your post to show the actual code?

Comment: @IbrahimFadel edited

Comment: Require path, `const path = require("path");` then try changing it to `fs.readdir(path.resolve(__dirname, "./"));`

Comment: @IbrahimFadel that fixed the problem. It seems that readdir was expecting a file path without the file:// prefix

Comment: There's missing something in the code. Could you please add more context of what you are trying to do? Are you reading specific directory inside electron app or any arbitrary directory, say, selected by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) expects data in form of `URL` instance or a path as `string`.

You pass a `string` here, so you're defining a path for `readdir`. Because your `string` is not actually a path, you should either

- use `readDir` directly (as it seems to be a path based on your code)
- or use a `new url.URL(url.pathToFileURL(readDir))`